# How to add a Dropdown Menu to a WorkbenchWindowControlContribution in RCP

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` in my Eclipse RCP application. It basically consists of an icon, a textfield and a button. Now I want to add a Dropdown menu between the icon and the textfield. How can this be done (in code)?